# Convert WAV to base64

Tags: c, python-2.7, audio, wav

I have some wave files (.wav) and I need to convert them in base64 encoded strings. Could you guide me how to do that in Python/C/C++ ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@ForceBru's answer

```
import base64 
enc=base64.b64encode(open("file.wav").read())
```

has one problem. I noticed for some WAV files that I encoded the string generated was shorter than expected.

Python docs for "open()" say

> If mode is omitted, it defaults to 'r'.
>   The default is to use text mode, which may convert '\n' characters to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading. Thus, when opening a binary file, you should append 'b' to the mode value to open the file in binary mode, which will improve portability.

Hence, the code snippet doesn't read in binary. So, the below code should be used for better output.

```
import base64
enc = base64.b64encode(open("file.wav", "rb").read())
```

Answer (score 6):

### Python

The easiest way

```
from base64 import b64encode

f=open("file.wav")
enc=b64encode(f.read())
f.close()
```

Now `enc` contains the encoded value.

You can use a bit simplified version:

```
import base64

enc=base64.b64encode(open("file.wav").read())
```

---

### C

See [this file](http://base64.sourceforge.net/b64.c) for an example of base64 encoding of a file.

---

### C++

[Here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html) you can see the base64 conversion of strings. I think it wouldn't be too difficult to do the same for files.